# Determine app sending SMS Premium messages

Tags: sms, permissions

I normally have "Block Premium Messaging" set up on the phones in my family. This is a verizon content block the prevents you (or family members) from sending messages to premium services that charge.

Recently, I had to replace a phone that broke and when the new phone was activated the blocks I had set up were cleared. On my bill was a $9.99 charge for a text to one of these premium services.

I know nobody sent the SMS to the service to sign up for this. I suspect some application on the phone sent the SMS message. Is there a way I can find out which app on my phone is sending SMS messages to premium services? Can I view all the apps that have permission to send SMS messages?

-- update -- well, I ran RL Permissions and no downloaded apps have the Send SMS permissions. I must have already deleted the offending app or something else is going on.

Comment: Don't edit the answers for updates pertaining to the question. I've moved your attempt to edit Lie's answer up here :P

Comment: Oh. I guess I clicked the wrong edit link. I thought I was editing my question. Doh!