# How can I stop my phone sending an SMS every time I insert a SIM card?

Tags: sms, sim-card

I have one Samsung tablet and one Samsung mobile phone. When I insert my Airtel SIM in tablet then it automatically sends one SMS to an unknown number, and when I insert the same SIM card into my mobile then it again sends one SMS to an unknown number. So every time an amount is deducted from my balance.

I don't know what is the problem and how to get out from this problem?

Is it a problem with the SIM card or with the mobile/tablet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32087/i-changed-my-sim-card-how-do-i-find-which-app-is-sending-sms-messages-to-my-ol

Comment: +1 for that hint with the duplicate, GreenGuy! @VinitVikash: Please check its [first answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/32117/16575), it pretty much sounds like a perfect match to your problem.

Comment: Here in my case "Sim change Alert" box is unchecked then why it send SMS??? All the setting are factory set.

Comment: NO this question is not duplicate of other question. Here in my case "SIM change alert" box is unchecked but it till send SMS when I insert new SIM into the mobile.

Comment: Have you followed the debugging steps used in that post? Install RL Permissions and see what apps ave permission to send SMS, and then which apps can start at boot. The culprit is likely one of the applications that has both permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I got solution after giving lot of time on this problem.
This is the defect of Samsung Software. Actually every software version is linked with some number. But it not send any sms to that number. Because of licence, security reason they need to linked every version to particular number. If some problem occur in mobile phone then only it communicate with this number. But in some particular software there is some defect that's why it send sms when new SIM inserted into mobile.

The solution is go to your nearest Samsung Service Center and update your software.

Answer (score 1):

Before changing the SIM, set your phone to flight mode. Then switch it off, and change the SIM. Switch on after 5 minutes, and disable the flight mode. It will help you save your balance deduction.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had enabled mobile tracker & that why the SMS's were going. Disable the tracker & the sms'es will not be send out on sim change.