# Detect Which App is Sending SMS

Tags: permissions, logging, sms

I noticed on my phone bill that I have a lot of sent SMS messages which I'm not aware of and can't find in the sms app. 
Is there a way to find out which app is sending these messages? And how to view the details of these messages on my android phone (I'm using Galaxy S7 Edge).

Comment: you can set permission on each app's sms usage(android version > 6.0). Go to settings -> Apps - > Permissions. Uncheck the Message/Sms.

Comment: You can begin your search by using a permission viewer/analyzer type app, such as [aSpotcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.aSpotCat&hl=en). They can categorize apps based on the common permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine app sending SMS Premium messages](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10115/determine-app-sending-sms-premium-messages)

Answer (score 1):

Well first take a look at what is your standard SMS App. If it is anything that is not native to your phone (e.d. third party App) or something you installed away from google play store (e.d. untrusted source) it can be some sort of malware.

But before jumping to conclusions it is recommended you check every app in your phone and try to see which apps are even capable of sending SMS. To check if the app is capable of sending SMS, go to your Settings -> Apps and than click on each App individually. It should display a list of permissions the App has on your phone. If you see that the app has the permission of sending and recieving SMS, but is not the App used normally for communication, **uninstall it immediately**. Of course, this doesn't include Apps such as Viber, because they can indeed send SMS messages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Dejan, I am using the stock sms app. For the permissions to send sms I have checked that and they are all look legitimate apps that I need to keep. 
My question was how to find out which app was sending these messages and how to view the content/details of the messages.

Comment: Well I guess in that case you'll need to go trough each app manually and look trough each message that has been sent. If you are still unable to find these messages than I can think of 2 possible factors. 

1. Human Factor
Somebody's been sending these messages from your phone and than deleting them

2. Malware
You have a malware on your phone and that is the cause of all these messages.

If it is the latter, or you have a reason to believe that you have malware installed, please backup your files and restore your phone (to factory) settings immediately, as this can be a huge problem.